# gparted live: df missing drives in Ubuntu VM

Tags: gparted, livecd

I'm using GParted live iso to attempt to do `zerofree`.

In the GParted GUI, I can see the same drives as when normally booted.

But when I open the terminal - still in GParted Live - `df` doesn't show `/dev/sda`.

I tried being `root` and `user`.

Comment: The `df` command would only show mounted filesystems.  Can you see the disk with `parted --list` and if so, are you able to mount it?

Comment: @GracefulRestart yes I can see my main drive! How do I mount it so I can `zerofree` it?

Comment: The documentation for `zerofree` says that the filesystem has to be unmounted (or mounted read-only) for it to work.  If you still want to mount the filesystem, you should be able to use the `mount` command.

Comment: @GracefulRestart `zerofree: filesystem /dev/sda1 is mounted rw1`. How do I unmount it?

Comment: You don't need to mount a partition in order to zerofree.

Comment: @realpclaudio I figured it out: I had `gparted` application opened simultaneously with the terminal so it must have mounted `/dev/sda1`. `zerofree` is working now (in root). Thanks.